# Must return only a description but returns all the path json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Must return the description of each title I tried to create the path for each one worked however returns all instead of each. Anyone know how to do?

javascript

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Frss.cnn.com%2Fservices%2Fpodcasting%2Fac360%2Frss.xml'%20AND%20itemPath%3D%22%2F%2Fchannel%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?", function (data) {

    // Load Titles patch Json
    console.log(data.query.results.channel.item);
    var titles = data.query.results.channel.item.map(function (item) {
        return item.title;

    });
    var urls = data.query.results.channel.item.map(function (item) {
        return item.origLink;

    });

    var descri = data.query.results.channel.item.map(function (item) {
        return item.description;

    });

    $(".description-podcast p").text(descri);

    console.log(titles);
    $(".container-list-podcast ul").append('<li>' + titles.join('</li><li>'));
    $(".container-list-podcast ul li").each(function (key, value) {
        var text = $(this).text();
        $(this).html('<a href="' + urls[key] + '">' + text + '</a>');
    });
    // Load Navigation Only Key
    a = $('.nav_holder li a').keynav(function () {
        return window.keyNavigationDisabled;
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cf5QU/7/)

Comment: Your description holds html values? What is wrong exactly?

Comment: I wanted to return me only the description of each item.

Comment: The object itself contains HTML, How do you prepare the object?